# How much time my app install from google play?

Tags: android, google-play

I upload my app to google play one week ago, and i want to know how much time the app install from google play? near the rating written 12, but i think that it is number of comment, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the right look for "Installs", under that, there will be a number

For example https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zeptolab.ctrexperiments.ads&feature=banner#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDIwMSwiY29tLnplcHRvbGFiLmN0cmV4cGVyaW1lbnRzLmFkcyJd

Installs:
    500,000 - 1,000,000

Comment: its means that installed 500,000+?